# Get content after a div within another div

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="mother">
   <div class="son">Content</div>
   <h3></h3>
   text
   <div class="anotherSon">Content</div>
</div>
```

So in this example I would like to get everything **after** the "son"-div within the mother-div (and save it in a variable). The content can be of any type, it can be text or elements. What's the easiest way to do this in jquery?

Comment: Rory has it. Just on an aside, it's more typical to use the terms "parent" and "child" than "mother" and "son" :-)

Comment: Yeah, would probably be way more pedagogic of me to use parent and child instead. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to include text nodes, you will need to use `contents()` and figure out the index of `.son` in relation to its parent:

```
var $contents = $(".mother").contents();
var sonIdx = $contents.index($(".son"));
var elements = $contents.filter(function(i) {
    return i > sonIdx;
}).get();
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNdtp/1/) which demonstrates.

Comment: Good thinking about including text nodes, +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `siblings()`

```
$('.son').siblings().next();
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GsLtN/14/)**

Comment: I do not want any content before the "son"-class, if there is anything before it I will probably get it with siblings-usage, right?

Comment: @Undrium:You need to use filter for that. However i would recommend you using a proper dom. manupulating text node is mess.

Comment: Good point, however this is user created content so it is a little bit out of my control.

Comment: Then RGraham gave perfect solution for your problem.