# scrape text after div within other div

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the html code:

```
    <h3 class="s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags" role="text">
        <div>
            <div class="s-item__title-tag">SOLD  Oct 9, 2018</div>
        </div>
        <span class="LIGHT_HIGHLIGHT">New Listing</span>MAX DELL PRECISION M4800 I7-4930XM EXTREME EDITION 3GHz 16GB 500GB SSD K2100 FHD
    </h3>
```

I want to get the "MAX DELL PRECISION M4800 I7-4930XM EXTREME EDITION 3GHz 16GB 500GB SSD K2100 FHD" but when I do:

```
pre_title_and_sold=rel_text.findAll("h3",{"class":"s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags"})
print(pre_title_and_sold)
```

I get

```
SOLD  Oct 8, 2018Dell Precision M6500 17" LED Workstation i7 1.6GHz 4GB RAM 111GB HD DVDRW Win 7
```

I want to get

```
"MAX DELL PRECISION M4800 I7-4930XM EXTREME EDITION 3GHz 16GB 500GB SSD K2100 FHD"
```

I'm thinking I could do the   [0].text   route (as I am iterating through a webpage) if I am able to remove the section

```
<div class="s-item__title-tag">SOLD  Oct 9, 2018</div>
```

I have tried to look at the documentation but was confused.
my question is somewhat similar to [Get content after a div within another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885255/get-content-after-a-div-within-another-div) but clarification is still needed.

python 3.5 with BeautifulSoup win 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the actual tag that contains the text. Check this code. I have provided 2 option to find the text!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<h3 class="s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags" role="text">
        <div>
            <div class="s-item__title-tag">SOLD  Oct 9, 2018</div>
        </div>
        <span class="LIGHT_HIGHLIGHT">New Listing</span>MAX DELL PRECISION M4800 I7-4930XM EXTREME EDITION 3GHz 16GB 500GB SSD K2100 FHD
    </h3>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find('h3', attrs={'s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags'}).span.next_sibling#first option
title1 = soup.select('.LIGHT_HIGHLIGHT')[0].next_sibling#second option
print(title)
print(title1)
```

Output:

```
MAX DELL PRECISION M4800 I7-4930XM EXTREME EDITION 3GHz 16GB 500GB SSD K2100 FHD
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am new to python and bs4, so much appreciated Sohan Das! Have a good day

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: For those who are using bs4 to webscrap ebay, just use their API (I did not know they had one before. Do your homework lol) see here: https://developer.ebay.com/products/developer